# How to connect to the four Ethernet ports on a wireless router?

Tags: ethernet, router, lan, dhclient, pppd

Let's say we are happy with our typical wireless router.
But one day we notice it has four LAN ports. We connect an Ethernet
cable from one of them to our computer. On our computer do we use:

- dhclient and the same SSID and password as we used for wireless?
- pppoe and the same userid and password our ISP gave us?
- One of the above, with no username or password?

Comment: I am probably missing something.  But, well, for one thing the SSID is only for WIFI, not for wired Ethernet. Also a lot of Linux based computers abstract the user from network details adding GUI controls to their desktops that should walk you through configuring WIFI or wired Ethernet connections.  As for a password, for a wired Ethernet connection you should just be connected.  No password required.

Comment: It seems to me that this question is better asked on the SuperUser site. There does not seem to be anything in the question related to the use or administration of Unix or Linux systems.

Comment: GUI interfaces: I want to do it manually instead so am asking here.

Superuser: well even regular Linux users would like to know how to connect to the Internet sometimes via these ports, hence I'm asking here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In most typical consumer-grade "Ethernet Router with WiFi Network Access Point" (i. e. "router") equipment, you can simply connect the Ethernet cable, and use the standard DHCP client on that interface (assuming a typical default configuration).  SSIDs and WPA passwords and only used for the wireless connection protocol and are not part of the basic TCP/IP connection itself.

That said, it is possible the configuration of the router may have been hardened somewhat (for example to only issue DHCP leases to known MAC addresses), in which case you may have to noodle around in the router's administrative interface-- which is beyond the scope of this question and this Stack.

Comment: In the simplest case would the command line just look like "dhclient enp1s0"?